# Does MonkeyTalk support PhoneGap Sencha Touch based Mobile Hibrid Application?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, monkeytalk, hybrid-mobile-app

We have a PhoneGap Sencha Touch based Mobile Hybrid Application, I want to use MonkeyTalk in automation testing.
Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

I installed monkeytalk-1.0.40, it works well. And with it, I can test native application very well.

I built a Hybrid Application with PhoneGap, it is very simple, the only 1 code is to load Sencha Touch example page:
    super.loadUrl("http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/index.html");

I also did everything following the MonkeyTalk's user guide (www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/install-agent/android).

Then, everything is ready, the simple Hybrid Application is deployed to the device simulator. The MonkeyTalk IDE can also connect to the application.
I record some actions (tap a field and typed some characters in it), but only some "WebView * tap" actions are recorded (without tap position information). When I replay it, it can also replay some tap actions, but without position, the tap position is incorrect.

So, I have to write some actions manually. I found sometimes the "Label  Tap" action can work, but sometimes it will tap on an incorrect element.
When I go into the form page (Kitchen Sink -> User Interface -> Forms on dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/index.html), I played an action to tap on a field, the whole UI moved to the left corner of the screen, very weird.
And, I tried to send some text to the "name" field, nothing happened.

Do you know what is the problem? Is it possible to fix? How should I do?

Thank you very very much!

Comment: Can you help on this? Thank you so much! ~ help ~

Answer (score 0):

I used MonkeyTalk and Sencha for quite some time now. As far as I understand, MonkeyTalk creates it's own IDs (the MonkeyIDs) for every (Web-)Element on the current view. Once an element got it's MonkeyID, it will keep it for the rest of the test.
The problem is, that Sencha does not create unique IDs for it's WebElements in the first place. Thats kind of confusing because it is simply illogical.

Anyways, what Sencha does is to generate IDs generic so they are only unique in the current view. When you switch to another view and come back later all elements might have different IDs. Maybe you can change this in the Sencha settings...

Thats why MonkeyTalk is not able to create the MonkeyIDs for those elements and while the MonkeyIDs are Monkeytalks only way to interact with elements you simply cannot click them, send text to them or interact with them in any other way.
The only solution to automate Sencha apps I found so far, is to use XPath and refer to an Element's label. But unfortunaly MonkeyTalk does not support that...

Answer (score 0):

Apps built using Sencha aren't the easiest to test because of what Steve McGarret said, but MonkeyTalk gets the job done using an alternate method explained in its [documention web page:](http://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-language-reference/command-syntax)

> MonkeyId’s can also be specified as a 1-based (not zero-based) index
>   of the form #N. In this case, the MonkeyId identifies the Nth
>   component of the specified type that’s currently displayed. Components
>   are indexed according to upper-left-most position, i.e., by sorting
>   components by (x,y) coordinate.

Imagine that you want to automate the registration of a user. The page will most likely contain several input fields but you can't use their ID's because they will change if you navigate to another view. Here's what you can do:

- Open chrome and use its web inspector (chrome://inspect/#devices) to look for the element you want. Let's assume an input box with the property "name" and value "firstName".
- Go to MonkeyTalk and open the Component Tree. Filter by the word "input".
- Note down its position in the tree (e.g. 3) and start writing your script:

  - Input #3 EnterText John
  - Input #4 EnterText Doe
  - (...)

And that's it. MonkeyTalk will play your script perfectly.
If someone else has a better solution to get the position of the element in the component tree please let me know - otherwise it's a pretty painful process if your page has lots of divs/elements and it's not worth the hassle. Might as well use another testing framework.